# Project doesnt run when i change folder name in lib folder

Tags: flutter, android-studio

i changed folder name to mian_screen and then when i run it gives error and cant find the path any more as you see in image.[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw0Pj.png)

Comment: could you share the contents of your lib folder? you can do so by executing `tree -L 2` in the terminal from within the `lib` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the way you are importing things.

Instead of doing `import '../models/orders.dart`

Try `import 'package:firstproject/models/orders.dart`